# How to only access one additional subdirectory and access their files utilizing batch?

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory, getdirectories

I usually program in Java, but for reasons I won't specify I am trying my hand at solving a problem utilizing batch scripting.  I have a couple directories that hold sub directories of days. For example I may have a folder called January and inside that folder are folders for each day (1, 2, 3, etc.) and inside those folders are the text files that I need to access.  However, this data is constantly updated so I never have a set number of folders.  I am wondering how I can access all the 'day' folders through a batch script?

I have been trying to iterate through the directories and figuring out what folders are inside the overall folder (ie: the month folder) by using the `/d /r` commands in a for loop.  However this only gives me the files in the directory.

Some code snippets that I've tried are:

```
FOR /D /r %%P IN (..\JAN\Processed\) DO (
copy filex.txt ..\JAN\Processed\%%~nxP
/* run a correlation program using the file located in the directory specified with the copy command */
)
```

I've also tried to use

```
for /r "..\JAN\Processed\" %%P in (.) do (/*similar to code above*/)
```

When I run this code, it will access every directory and not just the ones that I want (because I have additional directories in the 'day' folders).

To test my code I have also used the `ECHO` command a lot, just to see if it's actually finding the directories I need by putting `echo %%~nxP`, but it doesn't seem to find the directories I want to access.  It'll just return `ECHO IS ON/OFF`.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: you tried "`/D`irectories `/R`ecursive" and complain about too deep and you tried "`/R`ecursive" only and complain about files. Did you try "`/D` only?

Comment: @Stephan using only '/D' causes the echo statement to only print out the current directory that the command window is accessing.  Not even the folders/files inside of it.Using the example above, it would only echo "Processed"

Comment: Get a `for /d` to get the subfolders (only depth=1) and a second nested `for` to get the files in that subfolder: `@for /d %%P in ("..\JAN\Processed\*") do @for %%F in ("%%~fP\*") do @echo %%~fF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a `for /d` to get the subfolders (only depth=1) and a second nested for to get the files in that subfolder:

```
@echo off
for /d %%P in ("..\JAN\Processed\*") do (
  for %%F in ("%%~fP\*") do echo %%~fF
)
```